# Is there any way to configure the traffic load distribution based on percentage value

Tags: load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

We have two micro services Say Service MS-AA & MS-BB and we have configured the load as 10% for MS-AA & 90% for MS-BB from a third microservice-XYZ

Does Netflix Ribbon can solve my problem? If yes how to configure two services based on TPS percentage. Or there is any other library available to solve this requirement.

For details please refer the data flow diagram attached in this question link

Note :- Form TDM there is a RPC call not the end point call.

**Data Flow Diagram of Requirement**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WZLY.png)

Comment: Are they really separate microservices or instances of the same service? Ribbon does not have something like this out of the box. Spring Cloud Gateway has a weighted route predicate https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-weight-route-predicate-factory

Comment: Hello @spencergibb, Yes all are the seperate microservices. Also I have added the data flow diagram for more clarification